# how can I get the t-sql text in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am using SQL Server 2014 and want to know, how can we get the text of the tsql and who issued the command by using another function or join?

Comment: Check out `sp_whoisactive` http://sqlblog.com/blogs/adam_machanic/archive/2012/03/22/released-who-is-active-v11-11.aspx

Comment: The text of what tsql?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below command to check the active queries running on server along with the user name who fired it

```
   SELECT sqltext.TEXT,
s.login_name,
ExecReq.session_id,
ExecReq.status,
ExecReq.command,
ExecReq.cpu_time,
ExecReq.total_elapsed_time
FROM sys.dm_exec_requests ExecReq
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sql_handle) AS sqltext
INNER JOIN sys.dm_exec_sessions s ON ExecReq.session_id = s.session_id
```